# XCode 7 Storyboard segue usage confusion

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to make segue using storyboard, and I found it's really confusing for me. Sometimes, when I drag and drop segue push or modal, both will act like modal (bottom to up). And sometimes, it will act like push (right to left). I'm also using navigation controller to handle the right and left button. Do you know why it happens? How do we make sure that if we want to View Controller to animate right and left, we use push. and if we want to use modal, the View Controller to animate bottom to top. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you are using the correct type of segue -->

On the right hand side, after selecting the segue -->

[image]